# How to exit the "History Editor" mode in xcode 12.2?

Tags: xcode, git

Have a combination of buttons? Or am I missing the banal?
I can't get out of this mode ...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, just click the button with the opposing arrows in the upper right. It toggles the comparison mode.